# Breeze icons not working in thunar in list mode

Tags: icons, themes, openbox

I tried searching for anyone who had this specific issue but I only found issues about missing icons in thunar or other icon issues in pcmanfm

My issue is a bit more specific. I installed the breeze icon package. When I set the breeze icon package as my theme and icon it works perfectly in pcmanfm. But in thunar it only works while in icon mode. When in list mode pcmanfm works nicely however thunar shows this weird flat white icons.

(pcmanfm on left & thunar on right)

[image: Picture of pcmanfm(left) and thunar(right) in list mode]

[image: Picture of pcmanfm(left) and thunar(right) in icon mode]

Also another note, these white flat icons also appear when browsers / applications open up a file manager for browsing directories. For example when adding pictures on this website, the file manager that popped up also had the white flat icons as seen here:

[image: here]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using linux mint 20 ulyana, I understand that this is board is ubuntu specific. I just thought that since linux and ubuntu both based on the same thing and that a lot of questions related to icons have been asked on here I didn't think there would be a problem. If there is then I am more than happy to remove my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error and digging around I found out that my thunar view was zoomed out.

I didn't realize that when zoomed out the icons change appearance drastically.

When I zoomed in a little more the icons reverted back to normal